# How to have bold and non bold text in the same uilabel in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'am using Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.3 to create an iOS application.

I am displaying a text in a `UIlabel`. What I want to do is to make some parts of this text in bold and some parts underlined.
I used the `NSMutableAttributedString` to represent the text as I wish.
The problem is that I succeeded to have the underlined text but for the bold text I couldn't do it.
I made researches and I tried many codes from StackOverflow.com but no bold text was displayed.

Can someone please help me to resolve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Provide the code which you have tried

Answer (score 1):

To declare your label:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 300, 50)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

For underline, you certainly use something like:

```
 NSString *myText = @"My text here";
 CGFloat fontSize = 18.f;
 NSMutableAttributedString* attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myText];
[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]}
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, myText.length)];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                             value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
```

If you want a bold text, simply use bold font:

```
[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize]}
                            range:NSMakeRange(2, 8)];
```

And assign your attributed text to your label:

```
[label setAttributedText:attributedString];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: thanks, i tried your code but i always can't see the bold text :(

Comment: I updated my answer with more details. It works on my test project. I hope this helps.

Comment: i tried your code, i don't know why it doesn't work for me. My code : `  NSString *s =  NSLocalizedString(@"ScaleHint", @"PPP");
        NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString : s];
        CGFloat fontSize = 18.f;
        [string setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize]}
                                  range:NSMakeRange(2, 8)];   self.instructionTextLabel.attributedText = string;
        [self addSubview:_instructionTextLabel]; `

Comment: Well, I tried your code (with s = @"ScaleHint" and range = NSMakeRange(2, 7))....and it works...does the label's frame is correct? Do you set the font of your label? Maybe you could post your whole code. I updated my answer with all the stuff i put in the viewDidLoad of my controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension of UILabel that you can use when ever you want to Bold and/or color part of the strings in the label.

UILabel+bold.h

```
@interface UILabel (bold)
- (void)boldSubstring:(NSString *)substring andColor:(UIColor *)color;
@end
```

UILabel+bold.m

```
@implementation UILabel (bold)
#pragma mark - Attributed Text

- (void)boldRange:(NSRange)range andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    if(![self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)])
    {
        return;
    }
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.text];
    [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.font.pointSize], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color} range:range];

    self.attributedText = attributedText;
}

- (void)boldSubstring:(NSString *)substring andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    NSRange range = [self.text rangeOfString:substring];
    [self boldRange:range andColor:color];
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
NSString *fooStr = @"foo";
NSString *barStr = @"bar";

[self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", fooStr, barStr]];

[self.label boldSubstring:fooStr andColor:[UIColor redColor]];
// OR 
[self.label boldSubstring:fooStr andColor:nil];
```

And you can play with that concept to anything you actually want to do with UILabel attributed text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mainString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

NSAttributedString *firstPart = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                 initWithString:@"First " attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}];

NSAttributedString *secondPart = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"second" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName :@1}];

[mainString appendAttributedString:firstPart];
[mainString appendAttributedString:secondPart];

UILabel *mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
mainLabel.attributedText = mainString;
[mainLabel sizeToFit];
mainLabel.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:mainLabel];
```

I think the problem is that your custom font doesn't have BOLD style.

Comment: i have the color changed and the underlined text is displayed but no bold :(

Comment: @Heger 
Can you paste my code to empty project? In my empty project it works.

Comment: @Heger
Can you make NSLog or look in debuger that you don't have empty string? Wright after this: NSString *s = NSLocalizedString(@"ScaleHint", @"PPP")

Comment: I can see my string in the iOS simulator but the bold words are not bold , i simply see my string with the underlined words but the bold one is still in normal font

Comment: @Heger 
Please can you provide your code in question?

Comment: @Heger 
What font do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. You can change the font style as per your requirement

```
NSMutableAttributedString *firstText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"firstText"];
[firstText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:15.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, firstText.length)];
[firstText addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, firstText.length)];

NSMutableAttributedString *secondText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Second text"];
 [secondText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:18.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, secondText.length)];

[firstText appendAttributedString:secondText];
yourLabel.attributeText = firstText;
```

Hope this will help you.